# Nesting "rectangle split" inside "rectangle split" in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, multipart-node

I have created a node that resembles a stack.

The code I used is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[stack/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4, draw}]

    \node [stack] (0) {$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\vphantom{B}\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$
        \nodepart{two}$\vphantom{B}A$
        \nodepart{three}$\vphantom{B}B$
        \nodepart{four}$\vphantom{B}C$
    };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image: yield]

Now, I want to create something like this:

[image: goal]

I.e., four of these "stack" nodes nested inside one big "stack" node.
Unfortunately, I have not been able to do this.

Comment: Nesting TikZ pictures is problematic. Does the outer node need to be a rectangle split? We could just use a matrix of four rows and draw the horizontal parts separately.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel That might work! Though, I'm afraid, I don't really know how to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a matrix for the outer `rectangle split`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, matrix, calc}
\tikzset{
  four parters/.code=%
    \newcommand*\mathparts[4]{$##1$
                \nodepart{two}$##2$
              \nodepart{three}$##3$
               \nodepart{four}$##4$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  stack/.style={
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=4,
    minimum width=1cm,
    draw,
    execute at begin node=\strut}]
\matrix[
  every outer matrix/.append style={inner sep=.5cm},
  nodes=stack,
  matrix of nodes,
  four parters,
  draw,
  row sep=1cm] (m) {
  \mathparts{}{A}{B}{C} \\
  \mathparts{C}{}{A}{B} \\
  \mathparts{B}{C}{}{A} \\
  \mathparts{A}{B}{C}{} \\
}
foreach \row in {1, 2, 3} {
  ({$(m-\row-1.south west)!.5!(m-\pgfinteval{\row+1}-1.north west)$}-|m.west)
  coordinate (@) edge (@-|m.east)
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

You could also just do four matrices with each four nodes one below the other.

### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  stack/.style={
    draw,
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,
    every outer matrix/.append style={inner sep=.5cm},
    execute at begin node=\strut,
    nodes={draw, minimum width=1cm},
  },
  start chain=going below,
  node distance=+-1\pgflinewidth,
  split stack/.style args={#1/#2/#3/#4}{
    node contents={$#1$\\$#2$\\$#3$\\$#4$\\}}
]
\foreach \stack in {/A/B/C, C//A/B, B/C//A, A/B/C/}
\matrix[
  stack,
  on chain,
  name=chain-\tikzchaincount, % chains don't work nicely with matrices
  row sep=+-\pgflinewidth,
  split stack/.expand once=\stack];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

They both give the same output.

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution. Thank you very much!